# REST web API for mobile devices - CSRF protection?

Tags: php, facebook, api, security, rest

I know about CSRF attacks and protection against them inside and out, I've read the entire owasp page regarding it, but I'm a bit at a loss when it comes to protecting REST APIs.

I'm developing a RESTful web API for a mobile application. To authenticate users, I'm using an oauth server package (password flow grant) and my custom-built social grant for the facebook's manual login flow (we have both local and facebook accounts in our database). Both of these grants generate our application-specific access tokens that the client (mobile app) sends to the server with each request (in the Authorization header) to reassure that he/she is a logged in user.

Doesn't this alone mitigate the CSRF attack window? If not, what should I do to protect my server against these attacks?

P.S. I suppose checking the referrer header is not going to help here, because the referrer would differ from my server's domain, right?

Comment: Referrer is not always sent and easily spoofable. I wouldn't trust it at all as part of a security infrastructure.

Comment: You should read up about it on the owasp page, it IS a viable option: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#Checking_The_Referer_Header

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok first thing, CSRF attack requires one important application called `browser`. No one can simply trick your mobile application to send a request along with credentials to api server. So your mobile applications is particularly safe from CSRF attacks.

**However,** the problem arises if you use same api server for communications with web frontend(If your application has a corresponding web application too). In that case, you'd have to separate the API server for mobile application and web frontend, with CSRF prevention `ACTIVE` for web frontend API calls.**OR,** you can use the same API server, if you can somehow differentiate the call from web & mobile.

Comment: That's what I'm doing, actually: I have the API and two separate sets of controllers - one for the web and the other for the mobile clients. I already use CSRF protection with the web controllers, so I guess I'm safe.

Comment: @MantasD.Šimkūnas what method do you use for CSRF prevention?

Comment: How can you tell whether a client is a mobile or browser client?

Comment: @DobesVandermeer You can distinguish by set of parameters or a flag itself. However if you are concerned about, a web interface interacting with MOBILE API, which is not CSRF safe, you can simply keep different set of cookies for both, now if the attacker attempts to craft a request, from your browser to MOBILE API, he cannot, because of lack of correct credentials in browser cookies.

Comment: @mebjas thank you I hadn't thought of not using (the same) cookies for the mobile version but that solves the problem nicely.